# google is not crawling my angularjs website after adding sitemap.xml

Tags: ajax, angularjs, seo, google-crawlers

after reading multiple sources about angularjs and SEO (including google documentation), I understood that my 2 main options to get google to crawl my website are:

1. Add hashbang (#!) to my URL, and after the request from the crawling engine has reached my server (in the request, the #! is replaced by escape_fragment) I should render and response html snapshot using external services (like prerender.io) or implement myself.

2.Add hashbang (#!) to my URL - so that google could tell that it has a dynamically rendered data in this url, and add sitemp.xml to the website.
[as it is shown here](http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/#!sitemap_for_ajax_pages)

This is how I handle the route:

```
mi.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', { templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/Home/Home.html' });
$routeProvider.when('/items/:CatId', { templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/Items/Items.html' });
$routeProvider.when('/about', { templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/about.html' });
$routeProvider.when('/checkout', { templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/Checkout/Checkout.html' });
$routeProvider.when('/contact', { templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/contact.php' });
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });


$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

[This is my sitemap.xml](http://www.chefnoded.co.il/shop/sitemap.xml)

[my website](http://chefnoded.co.il/shop)

I saw in webmaster tools, that google recognized the new sitemap, but it didnt crawl them still.

Is there something I miss?

Comment: How were you able to determine Google didn't index your site?

Comment: looking at the searh results in: site:chefnoded.co.il/shop
and looking at the webmaster tools

Comment: It can take a while to cache

Comment: It was crawled over a week ago...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google Web Master tool - Section Crawl to see if Google have found some error when crawling your site.

You can also try the feature "Fetch as Google" which would provide great insight on how Google see your Angular application.

In your specific case some pages (link from sitemap) do not return any crawlable content even if you are sending 200 as HTTP response:

```
http://www.chefnoded.co.il/shop/#!/items/6

http://www.chefnoded.co.il/shop/#!/items/5

http://www.chefnoded.co.il/shop/#!/items/4
```

Comment: Hi, no errors from google webamster tools.
Those links from sitemap you posted, are  intentionally empty. It's for future use. Right now even the existing links are not desplayed in search results.
even when I search like that: "site:chefnoded.co.il/shop"

Comment: have you check your Robots.txt file?

Comment: I don't have robots.txt.
should I?

Comment: from what I understand, robots.txt, in my case, is good for telling google where NOT to crawl. If I dont have robots.txt it suppose just to crawl all the links